# Getting data from array to use in email

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following example of a series of checkboxes on a form:

```
<?php

echo $this->Form->input(
    'reason', array(
        'label'=>false,
        'type' => 'select', 
        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
        'options' => array(
            'Contact me' => 'Contact me',
            'Brochure request' => 'Brochure request',
            'Demonstration request' => 'Demonstration request',
            'Training' => 'Training',
            'Support' => 'Support',
            'Other' => 'Other'
        )
    ));

?>
```

This is then set as a variable in the controller like:

```
$this->set('reason', $this->data['Contact']['reason']);
```

And then in the email template I have tried doing this:

```
<?php var_dump( implode( ', ', $reason ) ); ?>
```

Which gives a result like: `string(28) "Contact me, Brochure request"` How do I remove those quotation marks and the string(28) prefix?

What's the best way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: if reason is an array of checked values, why are u using explode instead if implode? the latter would join the array values into a string to work with in your email template.

Comment: Okay changed that and removed the echo but getting issues with string prefix and quotation marks.

Comment: why are you using `var_dump`? that's intended behaviour.

Comment: Please suggest something different then. I basically want to list the values of that array :)

Comment: $a = implode(",", $array); and then get by $a[0], $a[1], ...

Comment: What if I don't know how many values there are though? Manually typing the value integer seems like a bad idea.

Comment: you can use an associative array, or a simple foreach.

Comment: Please can you post an answer with that as an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the [string helper/text helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/text.html). It has a built in `toList` function.

```
// controller
App::uses('String', 'Utility');
echo String::toList($this->request->data['Contact']['reason']);

// or
// controller
$this->set('reason', $this->data['Contact']['reason']);
// view
echo $this->Text->toList($reason);
// outputs 1, 2, 3 and 4
```

assuming `reason` is an array in the format:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => '1',
    (int) 1 => '2',
    (int) 2 => '3',
    (int) 3 => '4'
)
```

or just do a simple `foreach($reason as $k => $v) { echo $v; }`

Answer (score 0):

Trying accessing your reasons like this in the view:

Controller

```
$this->set('contact', $this->request->data);
```

View

```
$contact['Contact']['reason'];
```